# Netbeans updates

Tags: netbeans, ide

The Netbeans development environment is being updated? I notice that it has been some time since an updated version was published and some tools do not work with the latest JDK as the profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to NetBeans 8.2. Oracle is currently in the process of handing over NetBeans to Apache so the current situation is a bit messy:

- NetBeans 8.2 will be the final release of NetBeans 8.x from Oracle.
- Oracle also provide a [nightly DEV build of NetBeans](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) for that release which  contains bug fixes and enhancements. However, it looks like that nightly build recently ceased, since the most recent build is dated 3/28/18. I am guessing that there will not be any more nightly DEV builds from Oracle.
- The future lies with [Apache NetBeans](http://netbeans.apache.org/) which will be released shortly.
- You can download [Apache NetBeans 9.0 Beta](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html).
- However, you can also [download a zip of Apache NetBeans 9.0 Beta which contains bug fixes](https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/398/).

Apache NetBeans Beta supports JDK 9 and JDK 10, and I recommend using the zip file linked to in the final bullet point above.

The Profiler works fine with Apache NetBeans Beta.

Comment: Do you know if Apache Netbeans has some plugin to work with UML? I can't find any free for netbeans that support direct and indirect engineering. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alberto Yes, there are three UML plugins available, depending on what you want to do. To review/install them: select **Plugins** from the **Tools** menu, click the **Available Plugins** tab, then enter **UML** in the **Search** field. I just tried and it listed three UML plugins.